# ActionScript 3.0 Loading and Playing Multiple Sounds

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, soundchannel

I have written a loadSound function which handles loading and playing multiple sounds. This function works fine when I call this function in another keyframe i.e. the frame in which the function is not written. But when I call the function on the same frame in which the function is written the sounds gets mixed up. For example the function is written in 1st keyframe. If I call this function in 2nd, 3rd and 4th keyframe (with different sounds) it works fine. But when i call the same function in 1st, 2nd and 3rd keyframe it all gets messed up.
In 1st keyframe the sound plays properly. When I move to 2nd Keyframe the 2nd sound plays. But when I move back to the 1st keyframe the 2nd and 1st keyframe sounds all get mixed up. This doesn't happen when I call the function in 2nd, 3rd and 4th keyframes.

Below is my function:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

stop();

var s:Sound;
var localSound:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var req:URLRequest;
var loadedPct:uint;
var currentFrameArr:Array = ["One","Two","Three"];
var urlArr:Array = ["sound/m01_t01_s01.mp3","sound/m01_t01_s02.mp3","sound/page10_11.mp3"];



function loadSnd(currentFrm:String)
{
    s = new Sound();
    s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSoundProgress);
    s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
    s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);

    localSound.stop();

    for (var i:uint=0; i<currentFrameArr.length; i++)
    {
        if (currentFrm == currentFrameArr[i])
        {
            req = new URLRequest(urlArr[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    s.load(req);
}

function onSoundProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void
{
    loadedPct = Math.round(100 * (evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal));
    trace("The sound is " + loadedPct + " % loaded");
}

function onSoundLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    localSound = s.play();
}

function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("The sound could not be loaded: " + evt.text);
}
```

Call to this function in different frames:

```
loadSnd("One");
loadSnd("Two");
```

etc

If I pass the parameter 'One' in loadSnd it plays the 1st element in urlArray, 'Two' 2nd element and so on.

But if I include the soundChannel.stop() in my buttons it works fine though. Athough I would have liked to be embedded it within the function itself as I am planning to write a class file for this to be included in my project. Below code if included works just fine.

```
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNextClk);
function onNextClk(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
          localSound.stop();
          this.nextFrame();
}


prevBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrevClk);
function onPrevClk(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
          localSound.stop();
          this.prevFrame();
}
```

I was also thinking what would happen if the frame is changed without a mouseclick for example if an animation ends and a new keyframe starts and I would like to include a different sound file in that keyframe.
If the soundChannel.stop() is included in the function itself no matter whatever event occurs either a mouse click on a button or a animation end it would stop the previous sound and play a new one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am scratching my head over this for long.

Answer (score 0):

```
Got the Solution. The SoundMixer.stopAll(); statement did the trick. The complete workable function is pasted below:

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

stop();

var s:Sound;
var localSound:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var req:URLRequest;
var loadedPct:uint;
var currentFrameArr:Array = ["One","Two","Three"];
var urlArr:Array = ["sound/m01_t01_s01.mp3","sound/m01_t01_s02.mp3","sound/page10_11.mp3"];

function loadSnd(currentFrm:String)
{
    s = new Sound();
    s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSoundProgress);
    s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
    s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);

    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    localSound.stop();

    for (var i:uint=0; i<currentFrameArr.length; i++)
    {
        if (currentFrm == currentFrameArr[i])
        {
            req = new URLRequest(urlArr[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    s.load(req);
}

function onSoundProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void
{
    loadedPct = Math.round(100 * (evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal));
    trace("The sound is " + loadedPct + " % loaded");
}

function onSoundLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    localSound = s.play();
}

function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("The sound could not be loaded: " + evt.text);
}

Calling the function:

loadSnd("One");
loadSnd("Two"); etc
```